# Angular service pass data to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have search field in my `top-bar component` and I need to get input value of that search field in one of my components, but it doesn't pass the value.

#### Structure

1. Search service
2. Top bar component
3. Result component

#### Logic

1. `Top bar component` receive input value then pass it to `Search service`
2. `Result component` receive input value from `Search service` and do it's process

#### What I have so far

1. **Can** get input value in `Top bar component`
2. **Can't** get any value in `Result component`

#### Code

`TopBar component`

```
// HTML
<input nz-input nzBorderless placeholder="Search here..." (keydown.enter)="onInput($event)" style="background-color: #F3F6FC;" />

// SCRIPT

import { SearchServiceService } from 'src/app/services/search/search-service.service';
@Input() searchName: string;
constructor(
    private globalSearchService: SearchServiceService,
) {}

public onInput(event: any){
    // this pushes the input value into the service's Observable.
    this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.next(event.target.value);
}
```

`Search service`

```
export class SearchServiceService {
  public searchTerm: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  constructor() { }
}
```

`Result component`

```
import { SearchServiceService } from 'src/app/services/search/search-service.service';

public searchTerm: string = "";

constructor(
  private globalSearchService: SearchServiceService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  // this listens to the input value from the service and does something on change.
  this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
    console.log('search newValue :', newValue); // Nothing prints here!
    // this is where you would apply your existing filtering.
    this.searchTerm = newValue;
  });
}
```

**Any idea?**

#### Update

Q: How did I register my search service?

A:

```
import { SearchServiceService } from 'src/app/services/search/search-service.service';

const MODULES = [CommonModule, RouterModule, AntdModule, TranslateModule, InfiniteScrollModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]

@NgModule({
  imports: [...MODULES],
  declarations: [ACLComponent],
  exports: [...MODULES],
  providers: [SearchServiceService],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: I cannot see any reason for it not to work, here is a demo in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xevdp8

Comment: Can you share how you are registering your service?

Comment: @GouravGarg I have shared module and I placed it in there, I'll update my code

Comment: @GouravGarg updated

Comment: If I am understanding this correct you have something like this a shared module, top-bar module, result module. And you are importing your shared module in both modules?

Comment: @GouravGarg no, I have app module and shared module and result module. `ps:` result module has shared module imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

All I had to do was moving my service provider from shared module to app main module and rebuild (serve) my app.

Comment: Can you add an explanation for others?

Comment: @GouravGarg sure after I back to my system I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `BehaviourSubject` wrong here. Implement like so. also please don't expose all your variables as public and remove constructors not being used

```
export class SearchServiceService {
  searchTerm: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  $searchTerm = this.searchTerm.asObservable();
}
```

and then in your `Result Component` you subscribe to the `Observable`, not the `BehaviourSubject`

```
import { SearchServiceService } from 'src/app/services/search/search-service.service';

searchTerm: string = "";

constructor(
  private globalSearchService: SearchServiceService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.globalSearchService.$searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
    this.searchTerm = newValue;
  });
}
```

Comment: still not receiving value in my result component

Comment: @mafortis then I'm guessing it's your use of `public` on your `searchTerm` variable. I tried the same thing here and it works.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rpsffw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: There is absolutely no reason using asObservable will make any difference what so ever.

Comment: @Roj I don't have that `<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>`

Comment: @mafortis it's just a component that was added by stackblitz. you can remove it

Comment: But does nothing to answer the question

Comment: @Roj still somehow i can't get it in my results component, not sure why :/

Comment: @mafortis have you tried removing the `public` keyword? also try using a normal input to test in case there might be something up with `nz-input`. Also can you provide a stackblitz or plunkr link with your implementation so we can have a closer look?

Comment: @roj ok I try, stackblitz might take little time i'm not so good at it :D

Comment: @roj https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vkze4r?file=src/app/search.service.ts here works in my app not working! :'(

Comment: @mafortis haha. this is going to be difficult if i can't see the project. can you upload to github or something?

Comment: @Roj thanks man, I've already solved it :)

Comment: @mafortis nice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225643/discussion-between-roj-and-mafortis).